# How to set different aspect ratio for CameraX in android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-camerax

I am not able to find a solution for how to set different aspect ratio for a camerax I want the user to be able to click the photo in 1:1 4:3 16:9

Answer (score 0):

Android camera does not always support all aspect ratios. For example, 1:1 is not always supported. However, you can crop the camera output to achieve the same effect.

Without knowing what you are trying to accomplish, I suggest you starting with the [ViewPort API](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ViewPort), where you can customize a aspect ratio at the [ViewPort.Builder()](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/core/ViewPort.Builder#Builder(android.util.Rational,int)) constructor.